# How can I get RedirectAttributes in HandlerInterceptor.postHandle() method

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

- Background:
  A web project uses `SpringMvc` framework is required to front-back 
  seperation reconstruct. Frontend is going to use `React`, and some of the backend's `Controllers` which used to return `jsp` view need to return `jsonObject`. The data passed to `jsp` through `ModelMap` now needed to be transferred to `json` and write back through `Response`. And to avoid to modify every `Controller`, I came up with an idea of using `Interceptor` to get this job down. It works good for those `Controllers` pass data with `ModelMap`, but it dosen't for those pass data with `RedirectAttributes`.
- Problem:
  Some of the Controllers return `redirect` and use `RedirectAttributes` to pass attributes. Since `postHandler()` has only 4 params: `request,response,handler` and `modelAndView`, I can hardly get attributes of `RedirectAttributes` from these.

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="save")
public String save(CarInfoEntity entity, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model){
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "success!");
    return "redirect:/demo/carInfo/list";
}
```

Interceptor Code:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    if(modelAndView != null) {
        Map<String, Object> map = modelAndView.getModel();
        String json = JSON.toJSONString(map, SerializerFeature.DisableCircularReferenceDetect);
        logger.debug(json);
        if (null != json) {
            try {
                response.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                pw.write(json);
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        modelAndView.clear();
    }
}
```

Question 1: Can I get `RedirectAttributes` in Interceptors?
Question 2: How, if I can?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use `AOP`, perfect solved the problem. I found that `AOP` is more powerful than `Intercepter`. I can define `cut points` more flexibly and get all arguments with `getArgs()` method of `ProceedingJoinPoint`.